# Passing collection.fetch as a named function to collection.bind does not work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two Backbone collections. I want to bind to the reset event one one. When that event is fired, I want to call fetch on the second collection, like so:

```
App.collections.movies.bind("reset", App.collections.theaters.fetch);
```

The second fetch never fires though. However, if I pass an anonymous function that calls theaters.fetch, it works no problem:

```
App.collections.movies.bind("reset", function () { App.collections.theaters.fetch(); });
```

Any idea why this might be the case?

Heres my full code. I'm not showing any of the models or collections, because it's a lot of code, but let me know if you think that might be the source of the problem:

```
var App = {

    init: function () {
        App.collections.theaters = new App.Theaters();
        App.collections.movies = new App.Movies();

        App.events.bind();
        App.events.fetch();

    },

    events: {
        bind: function () {
            App.collections.theaters.bind("reset", App.theaterManager.assign);

            App.collections.movies.bind("reset", function () { App.collections.theaters.fetch(); });
        },

        fetch: function () {
            App.collections.movies.fetch();
        }
    },

    collections: {},

    views: {},

    theaterManager: {

        // Provide each model that requires theaters with the right data
        assign: function () {
            // Get all theaters associated with each theater
            App.theaterManager.addToCollection("theaters");

            // Get all theaters associated with each movie
            App.theaterManager.addToCollection("movies");
        },

        // Add theaters to a collection
        addToCollection: function (collection) {
            App.collections[collection].each(function (item) {
                item.theaters = App.theaterManager.getTheaters(item.get(("theaters")));
            });
        },

        // Returns a collection of Theaters models based on a list of ids
        getTheaters: function () {
            var args;

            if (!arguments) {
                return [];
            }

            if (_.isArray(arguments[0])) {
                args = arguments[0];
            } else {
                args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            }

            return new App.Theaters(_.map(args, function (id) {
                return App.collections.theaters.get(id);
            }));
        }
    }
};

$(function () {
    App.init();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This all has to do with function context.  It is a common confusion with the way functions are called in Javascript.

In your first way, you are handing a function to be called, but there is no context defined.  This means that whoever calls it will become "this".  It is likely that the equivalent will be of calling `App.collections.movies.fetch()` which is not what you want.  At least, I am guessing that is what the context will be.  It is difficult to know for sure... it might be jQuery, it might be `Backbone.sync`.  The only way to tell is by putting a breakpoint in the `Backbone.collections.fetch` function and print out the `this` variable.  Whatever the case, it won't be what you want it to be.

In the second case, you hand it a function again but internally, you specify the context in which the function is called.  In this case, `fetch` gets called with `App.collections.theaters` as the context.

... was that clear?

Comment: Got it. What I need to do is pass a context when I bind the event. Backbone allows you to do this: collection.bind("event", handle, context)

Comment: Well there you go!  I didn't realize the `colleciton.bind` gives you the ability to pass context.  Win!

Comment: I tried passing a few different contexts, none of which worked. I tried this, which is just the window object, App.collections.theaters,   and App.collections.movies. Still no luck.

Comment: I dunno... I'd have to play with it.  What is wrong with the function you've got?

Comment: Coffeescript compiles to the same thing, which I think is fundamentally wrong. Why can't I pass a named function directly?

Comment: @Adam That is how Javascript works.  You are dealing with functions and contexts.  When you pass a named function directly, you give up the context in which it runs.  I only suggested Coffeescript because it reads less offensively:  `App.collections.movies.bind "reset", -> App.collections.theaters.fetch()`